# Is ZK open source edition "write once, run anywhere"?

Tags: java, cordova, web-applications, zk

I've been looking into using [zk](http://www.zkoss.org/index_new.jsp?utm_expid=97361-15&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zkoss.org%2Fzkdemo%2Fgetting_started%3Frfi%3D1) for my upcoming Java web project, but am a little skeptical because as awesome as it seems, it has an expensive licensed edition as well as a free open source edition.

I could only use ZK Open Source edition but *need* the "write once, run anywhere" functionality (otherwise I will probably go with GWT/Phonegap).

On their [feature comparison page](http://www.zkoss.org/whyzk/Features), they don't mention write once/run anywhere, so I'm wondering if any battle-weary ZK veterans can weigh-in on whether this feature runs on the free version or not, and how well.

I need to support all web browsers, mobile web, all Android devices (including Nook/Kindle), all iOS devices, Microsoft devices (Surface, etc.) and Blackberry.

**Also**, if the free/open source edition *does* support this feature, how does it work? Nothing in the tutorials seems to indicate how it generates native executables for the various platforms in addition to a WAR...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

ZK only builds Java web archive files (war), it does not build native applications for Android, iOS, Nook, Kindle, or even stand alone applications for the desktop.

ZK web applications **only run in a Java application server** like Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty, Glassfish, etc.

In this sense, ZK is very similar to GWT and very disimilar to PhoneGap.

- With PhoneGap you build **phone applications** using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Your application is then displayed inside a native wrapper compiled for each phone platform. This is not intended for the web, *per se*.
- With GWT you build **web applications** in Java code. Some of this Java code actually gets compiled into JavaScript so it can run on the client side when appropriate, offering performance advantages if used well. Writing JavaScript code as Java has the advantage of going through the Java compiler for *type safety* and the like.
- With ZK you build **web applications** in Java code. Unlike GWT, this never becomes JavaScript - all your Java code runs on the server. ZK handles setting up the AJAX calls.

Programming in ZK feels as though you have a copy of the DOM as Java objects. ZK deals with initializing your `Controller` for a particular `View` and you can ask it to wire up any `Component` from the view. You then have those `Components` as objects and any changes you make are immediately (more or less) reflected on the client.

Now, ZK aside..

If you want to write code once to run on all web browsers as well as on all phones, the only option is to write a web application. At the curent state of technology, you will not be able to get native executables for all phones *and* a get a web application from the same code base. If you develop a web application (using ZK, GWT, IceFaces, Lift, Grails, whatever) you can expect the maximum penetration into the market as almost all devices have a web browser.

Finally, some personal opinions on ZK..

- The development cycle is fantastic, I love programming with ZK.
- The team and community is great also, lots of momentum.
- The framework is actively evolving, new core features and improvements all the time.
- I'm not sure how it would stack up against the others under heavy load.

  - The DOM they generate is very heavy
  - There is a lot of chatter between the client and server

**Edit:**
PS: I found this old reference to something called [ZK Mobile](http://www.zkoss.org/download/zkmobile) which I think is now a dead project. My impression is that it was probably aiming to be something similar to PhoneGap in that it would just wrap your ZK website in a native Android application. Everything would still work over the internet but the user would have an icon on their phone. You wouldn't have access to any native functionality like alarms or the like.
Anyway, just thought I'd put it here for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks @Sean Connolly (+1) - one followup question: if you say ZK doesn't support native binaries (for Android, iOS, etc.), then what do they mean by their "write once, run anywhere" verbiage which appears on (virtually) every page of their site? Thanks again!!

Comment: They are being sales men here lol. They're talking up the responsive design on their UI side - when your web app is viewed in a tablet or phone ZK will/can render your view differently. If you look at their real [feature list](http://www.zkoss.org/whyzk/Features) you'll see no mention of actual device support, just things like `Responsive Design & Components`. To be honest though, *true* responsive design isn't just adjusting the font size; it's completely reconsidering the user experience appropriate for the device. In that sense, ZK **can't** offer *true* responsive design out of the box.

Comment: Also, it looks like with ZK EE (which you don't want to pay for anyway) you can get components like [CardLayout](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Layouts/Cardlayout) and [ScrollView](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Tablet_Devices/Components/Scrollview) which give a very 'phone like' interaction to your webapp.